# How to set a file image in a folder when the user didnt upload the file at the form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, image-upload

I'm having a lot of problems with my form. I have made a form for creating a user. The user can set a image to his profile, so I'm having complication when the user doesn't select a image. When the user doesn't select the image I want to set a default image. I don´t save the name of the file in database I simply set the image name as the id of that user. Here is my code:

```
public function uploadPic($id){

    $pic['upload_path'] = 'public/img/usuarios';
    $pic['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $pic['file_name'] = $id;
    $pic['overwrite'] = true;
    $pic['max_size'] = 800;

    $this->load->library('upload', $pic);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('foto'))
    {
        //here should be the default image;

        $result = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        return var_dump($result);

    }
    else
    {
        $img = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $ext = $img['upload_data']['file_ext'];

        $this->cropPic($img['upload_data']['full_path']);
        $this->usuarios_model->updateUserExt($id, $ext);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well.. don't set anything and just **check if uploaded -false-> load default pic | yes-> load uploaded image**.

Comment: How? Could give me a example I'm kinda new with programming

Comment: I can't, there isn't enough code/effort, just use `if` statements.

Comment: Actually, I need to save a file for the user image. It should save the default file but the file name should be his id